# Perforce: Is there a straightforward way to track a code change to the original submission?

Tags: version-control, integration, perforce, change-tracking, revision-history

I have a source file `//code/main/Foo.cpp` whose line *N* was changed. After a combination of `p4 annotate` and `p4 filelog`, I found the change came in from a branch. (This is my understanding of e.g., `git blame`.)

Drilling into that branch I again used a combination of `p4 annotate` and `p4 filelog` to find the line change came from an integration from yet another branch.

Drilling into *that* branch I again used a combination of `p4 annotate` and `p4 filelog` to find the actual changelist that contained the original submission that eventually led to changing line *N* in `//code/main/Foo.cpp`.

Is there no easier way to do this? I would like to point to a line in a file and say, "Where and when did that line first appear as currently written in the depot?"

What I want, then, is a *deep* `git blame` that traces a change all the way back to its origination.

Comment: Have you tried `p4 annotate -i` or `p4v`'s Time-Lapse View with "Show Branch History" enabled?

Comment: The version I am interested in is `p4 annotate -I`, which is the deep version, but yes that's exactly what I wanted. Can you make it an answer so I can give you proper credit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `p4 annotate -i` to follow history if the file was branched and `p4 annotate -I` to follow history from integrations to the file.